# Zeckendorf numbers the Clojure way

Tags: beginner, algorithm, clojure, fibonacci-sequence

I'm just getting into Clojure, and I wanted to make sure I am writing code the "Clojure way". The challenge I took on is [Zeckendorf numbers](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Zeckendorf_number_representation) (fairly trivial).

```
(defn fibs-until
  ([n]
    (vec (if (< n 3)
      (range 1 (inc n))
      (concat [1 2] (fibs-until n 1 2)))))
  ([n a b]
    (let [fib (+ a b)]
      (if (> fib n)
        []
        (cons fib (fibs-until n b fib))))))

(defn zeckendorf
  ([n]
    (if (= 0 n) "0" (zeckendorf n (reverse (fibs-until n)))))
  ([n fibs]
    (if (= fibs [])
      ""
      (let [head (first fibs) tail (rest fibs)]
        (if (or (> head n) (= 0 n))
          (str "0" (zeckendorf n tail))
          (str "1" (zeckendorf (- n head) tail)))))))
```

A few review questions I have:

1. Is there a more "Clojure way" to do this?
2. I noticed that I am repeating the same (overloading-esque) pattern of defining functions that have two arities, and calling out to the second in the first. Is there a better way to do this?
3. I wanted to use `[[head & tail] fibs]` rather than `[head (first fibs) tail (rest fibs)]` but I get a stack overflow.  Why is this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Starting with your last question first, I'm surprised that you don't always get a stack overflow. Clojure does not support tail-call elimination, meaning that purely recursive functions (like both your `fibs-until` and `zeckendorf`) are likely to blow up the stack.

There are various reasons why this isn't an issue in practice, first and foremost of which are Clojure's [lazy sequences](http://clojure.org/sequences).

Elements of a lazy sequence aren't generated until they're used. Among other things, this means that Clojure can easily handle infinite sequences. So a more idiomatic way to implement Fibonacci would be to return an infinite lazy sequence from which you can simply `take` however many elements you want. There are lots of ways to implement this, one of which is to simply wrap a recursive implementation with `lazy-seq`:

```
user=> (defn fib [a b]
  #_=>   (lazy-seq
  #_=>     (cons a (fib b (+ a b)))))
#'user/fib
user=> (take 10 (fib 1 1))
(1 1 2 3 5 8 13 21 34 55)
user=> (take 20 (fib 1 1))
(1 1 2 3 5 8 13 21 34 55 89 144 233 377 610 987 1597 2584 4181 6765)
```

Or, closer to your `fib-until` function:

```
user=> (take-while #(< % 100) (fib 1 1))
(1 1 2 3 5 8 13 21 34 55 89)
```

There are [lots](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/clojure.core/iterate#example_666) [of](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/clojure.core/lazy-cat#example_850) [other](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Clojure_Programming/Examples/Lazy_Fibonacci) ways to implement Fibonacci lazily in Clojure.

I'll leave a lazy version of `zeckendorf` as an exercise ;-)

Regarding your question 2, using multiple arities the way you do is common and nothing to be concerned about IMHO.